# Are there explicit canonical metrics on spheres which are not round?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

On a manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^n$, the most canonical metric is the round one. It is also known that there are a large number of Einstein metrics on spheres which are not round. Are there explicit canonical metrics on $\mathbb{S}^n$, however? For example, explicit metrics of constant scalar curvature? Explicit Einstein metrics?

By explicit, I mean that I have an explicit local coordinate expression for the metric.

I am interested only in the case $n \geq 3$.

Comment: I suspect if you read a few Robert Bryant replies on this forum you will get some answers to a few of your questions.

Comment: A general idea is to find such a metric in warped product form or which is conformal to a known one.

Comment: Berger's spheres? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berger%27s_sphere